What is the advisable unplugging procedure when using an external NVMe PCIe SSD drive via USB?
From a broken laptop computer, I removed the SSD and installed it in an external drive enclosure that supports NVMe and PCIe and attached it via a USB cable. I briefly looked at the directory structure and it appeared correct and so I can say tentatively that this procedure is a successful recovery of data from the broken computer.
When I use a USB Flash drive and right click in Windows Explorer I see an "Eject" option and after selecting it I see "safe to remove".  In the case of the external NVMe PCIe SSD plugged in, Windows Explorer is not offering the "Eject" option so how would I know when it is safe to unplug the USB cable?

If you open the Disk Management control panel, you can 'offline' the drive after which it's safe to remove. I think windows remembers though so you'd have to undo this if you re-insert the drive.
